# How to install carliv touch recovery on my MediaTek MT6572

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, boot

I own a **spice mi 356** which have a dual core 1.0 ghz processor. It is a MediaTek device with MediaTek version **MT6572**. Now, my question is to *install carliv touch recovery(a clockworkmod based recovery)* on my device. I cant install CWM because my device doesnot support it. I found on google that any mtk device which is not supported by cwm can install carliv as it is based on cwm and easy to use. I studied many sites on google that had the way to install carliv but they were out of my mind. So can anybody clearly understand the steps to me. My device has gone into bootloop twice and I know if i have a backup, I can easily restore my device so please anybody help me. If you want some details, comment it. I will surely give it out.[image: THIS IS THE SCREENSHOT OF DETAILS OF MY DEVICE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It is very easy to do so by following these steps.

First, you need to have your device rooted. If you have not rooted your phone yet, try to root it using Framaroot [(Official XDA thread)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276) , a one click rooting app that roots your phone, and installs the SU binary and the SuperSU app directly, without the need of plugging it into the PC. For rooting MediaTeK devices, try to apply the Boromir, Faramir and/or Barahir exploits. Download the latest version of the application [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2784451&d=1402084843).

Next, you have to install ADB (Android Debug Bridge) drivers to your PC (Pdanet drivers will do). Note that computers with Windows 8 and/or 8.1 aren't recommended for installing unsigned drivers. I would recommend you to use Windows 7 or an earlier version of Windows instead.

Next, you need to download and install the "CWM Magic Create" program on to your PC. This program will install the ClockWorkMod-based Carliv Touch Recovery to your phone in a simple and easy way.

You need to have an USB data transfer wire to connect your smartphone to any of your computer's USB ports.

Next, you'll have to enable USB debugging to your device if you have not enabled it yet. Run the CWM Magic Create program and follow its steps accordingly to install Carliv Touch Recovery to your MediaTeK smartphone.

Good luck!

For more information regarding the process, the CWM Magic Create tool and the Pdanet drivers, visit [this link](http://www.gizmochina.com/2014/07/03/how-to-install-cwm-to-you-mtk-device/).

Comment: Thanks, I just solved my problem and installed carliv touch recovery.

Comment: @AdityaSinha , If you think the answer is correct, you should mark it as the correct answer. This will help people who browse through the site to understand the correct way to do so. Another thing to be followed is to upvote the answer instead of adding a 'Thank You' comment. Please do so as soon as possible and uphold the rules of this website. Thanks for using this site!

Comment: But i don't know how to get the recovery.img. So, i am trying and i think that the answer is correct. Its acceptable. Thanx for reply.